# Lubuntu 17.04 LiveUSB boot hang

Tags: boot, lubuntu, live-usb

I'm attempting to make a bootable USB stick with Lubuntu 17.04 64-bit. I made the USB using Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 14.04, so it threw the "gfxboot.c32 not a COM32 image" error; when I attempted to bypass with "boot:live" it threw an ACPI error, so I added "acpi=off" to the boot parameters for live boot, and now it just hangs after I give it the "boot:live" command.

Without an error message I'm at a loss to troubleshoot it myself. I'm going to try Lubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 and see how that goes, but figured I'd ask here in the meantime because I've gotten many good answers from this community in the past.

System information:
-ZaReazon Chimera 2 laptop
-Intel i7-4710MQ CPU
-8GB RAM
-120GB hybrid SSD/HDD
-nVidia GeForce 970M graphics card
-Intel 7260 wireless adapter

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: Lubuntu 14.04 hangs at a black screen after picking live boot from the GUI.

Update 2: Lubuntu 16.04 behaves as 17.04, with similar solutions tried.

Update 3: Tried a different USB stick; same problems across all releases.

Update 4: Xubuntu 16.04/17.04 behave as their Lubuntu counterparts.

Comment: Did you try reformatting the Stick and putting the image back on?  I think I have gotten that error when using a bad USB stick.

Comment: Have tried reformatting with no success. I'll see if I've got another stick lying around to try in case this one's a dud.

Comment: Thanks for adding the computer specs into your original question :-) Let us hope that users with the same computer model or a similar one will see your question and contribute with their experiences and advice. As far as I can understand, this computer should be able to run standard Ubuntu as well as all the community flavours. Lubuntu should fly :-)

Comment: I think the nvidia card needs the boot option `nomodeset` to run with simple graphics, and after installation you should install a proprietary graphics driver. There are several questions about that at AskUbuntu, for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator in the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS family (including Lubuntu) is buggy. The new version introduced in version 16.04 LTS is a cloning tool and much more reliable.

You can use another cloning tool in order to make USB boot drives in Lubuntu 14.04 LTS, for example **Disks** alias `gnome-disks`, which is part of the release, and **mkusb**, which you can install from a ppa according to the following link.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

Cloning is a very reliable method to create an Ubuntu USB boot drive, and will eliminate several problems. But there are other things, that can cause problems, for example

- Bad download: Please check that the md5sum of the iso file matches the listed value at

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)
- ACPI, APIC ... : There may still be problems that can be worked around with boot options.
- graphics: You may have problems with the graphics chip/card, that can be fixed temporarily with the boot option `nomodeset` and later on fixed in the installed system with a proprietary driver.

  Edit: Now that I know that you have an nvidia card, I think that you need the boot option `nomodeset` to run with simple graphics, and after installation you should install a proprietary graphics driver. There are several questions with good answers about that at AskUbuntu, for example [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)
- wifi: You may have problems with the wifi chip/card, that can be fixed in the installed system with a proprietary driver.

---

You help us help you, if you specify your computer, at least

- Brand name and model
- CPU
- RAM (size)
- internal drive (size)
- graphics chip/card (brand name and model)
- wifi chip/card (brand name and model)

Answer (score 0):

Format and then try Universal USB installer, https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/