# Ubuntu 16.04 not shut down or restart my computer from the "Try Ubuntu" option

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, grubrescue

About a few weeks ago I tried to install Ubuntu 17.10 alongside with Windows (64bit, UEFI secure boot enabled) in my laptop and there was this "grub rescue" problem after the installation, where I couldn't boot either to Windows 10 or Ubuntu 17.10. Before starting the installation I made one partition (30 GB) in C:/ but I was facing some problems as long as I was trying to shrink the volume (it was showing "not enough space" even if there was plenty of gb), but after keep trying several times the partition was ready and I've started the installation (also I never disable UEFI secure boot). After the grub rescue problem and when finally I manage to boot on Windows I deleted the 30 Gb partition, extended the C:/ drive and did a bunch of thing I read on Internet (system recovery, fix mbr commands, changed the boot priority, and so on) in order to make my laptop boot normally directly to Windows. This problem has been fixed and my laptop is now booting normally to Windows. Today I attempted to install Ubuntu 16.04 this time, but before installation I selected the "Try Ubuntu" option and it's even not working the restart/shut down button -really stuck everything when I try shut down or restart the computer and I'd like to know if there is a way to secure the procedure before starting the installation and not having those boot problems again. I 'm very new to all this so I 'm sorry for my clumsiness in advance.

Comment: Please tell us about your computer: brand name and model, and also about the graphics card and wifi card. Knowing this will help us help you.

Comment: It's an Asus FX553V notebook, 8GB RAM i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.8GHz, for graphic card it use Intel HD Graphic Card 630 and NVIDIA GeFOrceGTX 1050 and WiFi card is Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265.

Comment: The nvidia card indicates, that it should help to use the boot option `nomodeset`. See these links, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/954603/lubuntu-17-04-liveusb-boot-hang/954652#954652