# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS amd64 installer still freezing while install it from UDB drive

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, pcie

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS amd64 to my Asus X541UV laptop, but the installer freezing every time. I tried a lot of methods I found, but none of them worked. Sometimes the installer crashed and started writing PCIe bus error messages. I found in some websites, maybe the Nvidia card makes the problem, but I not found any solution that solved my problem. I hope you can help me in this problem.

I use Windows 10 x64 as main system, Intel i3-6006U, Nvidia GeForce 920MX, 4 GB RAM, 500GB HDD.

Thank you everyone

Comment: Did you verify the download was perfect? or validate your install-media?  (an option before you select try/install ubuntu)  I would suggest your verify your install-media to ensure your download & write is flawless (cheap insurance that saves hours of debugging)

Comment: I think you need the boot option `nomodeset` because of the nvidia graphics card. See [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) and links from it. The following links and links from them may also help: [link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935300/when-booting-from-a-live-usb-graphics-error/935345#935345) and [link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954603/lubuntu-17-04-liveusb-boot-hang/954652#954652)